# TikTok Login Kit - unable to get access token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, access-token, tiktok

I'm currently testing it in Postman, following the guides below:

- create an app: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/getting-started-create-an-app
- fetching access token: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/oauth-user-access-token-management/

However, I keep getting errs when trying to get the access token:

- Error: invalid_request, Description: The request parameters are malformed.
- Error: Could not complete OAuth 2.0 token request

Here are my settings on the Authorization tab

- grant type: authorization code
- callback url: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback (authorize using browser)
- auth url: https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=123
- access token url: https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/
- client id: 123
- client secret: 321
- scope: user.info.basic
- state: state123456
- client authentication: send as basic auth header

Here it is on Postman:

[image: Postman setup]

When I hit `get access token`, it correctly directs me to the TikTok authentication (ie TikTok wants to access your acc) page, but after hitting continue on that it'll redirect me back to Postman and err out.

These are my headers:

[image]

My app has previously been reviewed & approved, but I made a few changes so it's back in `staging` - I'm not getting a redirect_uri err which you would if your app was in submission, so not sure if this could be causing it as well?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!